# Why do I get extrafontsizes error option in memoir class?

Tags: memoir, fontsize

I have this weird problem with my code in `memoir` class

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[25 pt]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\Huge text

\end{document}
```

It actually works fine when the option of `memoir` is equal to or less than `17 pt`, however, when I changed the option to `20 pt` or larger, I would get error like

> The `extrafontsizes' option is required to use (memoir)
>   the`25pt' option.
>   {The 17pt option will be used instead}

Could someone help me on that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply use `\documentclass[extrafontsizes,25pt]{memoir}`.

Comment: That works! You can make it an answer and I could accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear:

> `Class memoir Error: The 'extrafontsizes' option is required to use (memoir) the '25pt' option. ... {The 17pt option will be used instead}`

Simply use `\documentclass[extrafontsizes,25pt]{memoir}`